# mysql: select statement giving error

Tags: mysql

I know that I'm using wrong title because I can't think of a proper term for my problem. I am doing a document tracking system.

Here is the problem: the document need to be signed by the lower personnel first before the next personnel who is in a higher position.

In order to do that, I came up with the idea of using level on my table.

But I lack MySQL knowledge. This is my MySQL table:

[image]

This is my MySQL query. The problem is, I don't want to show to 
LHPL003 the document yet because the other signatorylevel lower than his has not yet signed the document (colum status will become 0 if the signatory signed the document).

How can I do that?

```
SELECT `tracknum`, `signatoryid`, `signatorylevel`, `status`
from tble_transaction 
where signatoryid = "LHPL003" and signed = 'Released' and signatorylevel <= "3";
```

question number 2:

i have problem with my first question

now i have this table

[image]

how can i do this.  example the user with the level 1 already signed the document so it become 
LHPL005 status = 0

what i want is a query that only LHPL004 can see the document

LHPL003 and LHPL002 cant see the document first because those who have lower lever than theirs didn't signed yet the document

Comment: u want to display the row having the status as 1 and having minimum signatory level ?? is this understanding is correct??

Comment: i want to display the row having status as 0 and having minimum signatory level (which is input from the user)

Comment: is it minimum signatory level or which is inputted from user?

Comment: yes its user input

Comment: Can you please tell the input and output what you give and what you want, m unable to understand the  context

Comment: SELECT `tracknum`, `signatoryid`, `signatorylevel`, `status`
from tble_transaction 
where signatoryid = "LHPL003" and signed = 'Released' and signatorylevel <= "3"; that is my query sir. but what i want is LHPL003 cannot see the document because someone who has a lower lever than him didn't sign the document first. what i want is he can only see the document when all of the signatories lower than his level signed the document

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `tracknum`, `signatoryid`, `signatorylevel`, `status`
from tble_transaction 
where signatoryid != "LHPL003" and signed = 'Released' and status='0' and signatorylevel <= "3";
```

Comment: what i want is to show the row having status as 0 and having the minimum level (which is a input from the user) whats lack on my query is how do i show only the status having 0 with the minimum level(user input)

Comment: i have question number 2 sir. kindly help me again

Answer (score 1):

To display  the rows having status as 0 and having minimum signatory level (which is input from the user)

```
 SELECT tracknum, signatoryid,signatorylevel, status from track where status=0  and signatorylevel < 4 order by signatorylevel limit 1;
```

**EDIT:**

*The above query will result only 1 record if you want multiple records use the following query*

```
select * from track where signatorylevel = (select min(signatorylevel) from track where status = 0 and signatorylevel < 4 );
```

Comment: i have question number 2 sir. kindly help me again

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand exactly what you want, But I think one of those 2 queries has the solution for you:

```
SELECT * FROM `tble_transaction` as t1
WHERE signatoryid = 'LHPL003' and signed = 'Released'
AND EXISTS (select 1 from tble_transaction where signatorylevel < t1.signatorylevel and status = 0)
```

Second one:

```
Select * from tble_transaction where
 signatorylevel < (SELECT min(signatory level) FROM `tble_transaction` as t1 WHERE signatoryid = 'LHPL003' and signed = 'Released' and status = 1)
ORDER BY signatory level desc
Limit 1
```

Second question:

```
SELECT * FROM `tble_transaction` as t1
WHERE signatoryid = 'LHPL005' and signed = 'Released'
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 from tble_transaction where signatorylevel < t1.signatorylevel and status = 1)
-- ORDER BY signatorylevel LIMIT 1 -- you can ignore this if signatoryid is UNIQUE
```

Comment: i have question number 2 sir. kindly help me again

Comment: try it now @Audrey

Comment: It gives me error sir 
3 errors were found during analysis.

    Unrecognized keyword. (near "NOT" at position 99)
    Unrecognized keyword. (near "EXISTS" at position 103)
    Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 110)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106136/discussion-between-wajeeh-and-audrey).